# laravel isn't rolling back(delete inserted records) when error occures

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this simple function and I want to make laravel transaction. It is inserting the first(SecondaryShare) while the second(Primary Share) contains error and I want to rollback and delete the SecondaryShare once the error occured.

```
try {
    DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
        $Share = new SecondaryShares();
        $Share->secondary_name = $request->secondaryName;
        $Share->primary_id = $request->primaryId
        $Share->save();

        //error in primaryname==> correct is primary_name
        $Share = new PrimaryShares();
        $Share->primaryname = $request->primaryName;
        $Share->percentage = $request->percentage;
        $Share->visibility = $visibility;
        $Share->save();
    });
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    dd('failed');
}
dd('worked');
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain further what does not work with the given code?

Comment: you sure the code in the catch block is executed? Also what does this code do? Some statements are [implict](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html) commiting in MySQL and might also [not](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html) be possible to rollback.

Comment: I have two tables primary and secondary.
I put a deliberate error in primary share.
First of all it will insert the secondary share and then go through the code to primary.
Once the error occurs, I want to delete the inserted secondary share before

Comment: i advice you to provide a table structures (`SHOW CREATE TABLE table`) for both tables, And post the SQL code which is generated from this code..

Answer (score 3):

You are using the transaction system the wrong way. There is two ways to use it and you are mixing them up, although that should never be done.

#### Option 1: Transaction Closure

You can put your code into a transaction closure. As soon as an `Exception` (actually `Throwable`) or **any exception type inheriting from these types** is thrown, the transaction will be rolled back and the exception will be re-thrown by the closure handler:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $model1 = MyModel::create();

    // model2 will not be created if model1 couldn't be created
    $model2 = MyModel::create();
});
```

You can also wrap the transaction closure with a try-catch to catch any transaction exception:

```
try {
    DB::transaction(function () {
        $model1 = MyModel::create();

        // model2 will not be created if model1 couldn't be created
        $model2 = MyModel::create();
    });
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    Log::error('Insert failed', ['exception' => $e]);
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}
return redirect()->route('form.success');
```

#### Option 2: Transaction Control

Or alternatively, you can control the transaction logic yourself. But be careful, this way is more dangerous because it happens quite easily that one forgets a rollback or commit:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

$model1 = MyModel::create();
if ($model1->exists !== true) {
    DB::rollBack();
    Log::error('Insert 1 failed');
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}

$model2 = MyModel::create();
if ($model2->exists !== true) {
    DB::rollBack();
    Log::error('Insert 2 failed');
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}

DB::commit();
return redirect()->route('form.success');
```

In my opinion, using option 2 yields a lot more code and is less readable.

---

By the way, Laravel is using custom database exceptions. It will throw a `\Illuminate\Database\QueryException` and no `\PDOException`.

Comment: *"In my opinion, using option 2 yields a lot more code and is less readable."* matter of opinion that option 2 can be more clear that you open a transaction and then a model does not exists you are going to rollback if everything is ok do a commit, the first option is more verbose because you don't know what is happening under the hood without seaching it in the documentation.. The function should maybe be called `DB::transactionAutoCommitOnSuccessAndRollbackOnException` then you know whats happening when you read the function name

Comment: it is thrown in catch even if pdo exception.
option 1: same as what I'm using
option 2: won't delete model1 if model2 throws error

Comment: you sure you are running InnoDB as table engine? @ahmad , thats why i asked you for create table structures.

Comment: It is thrown because you catch the wrong exception. But it doesn't matter because the closure will roll back the transaction anyway. At least as long as you are not intervening manually with `DB::rollBack()`.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The code and the logic of `DB::transaction($closure)` is extremely straight forward. Yes, Laravel is abstracting a lot of the actual transactional logic by providing this closure, but that doesn't mean it is a bad thing. From my experience, I can tell you we had more bugs in production with option 2 than with option 1. And the documentation of option 1 clearly states how it works - no need for an exaggerated method name.

Comment: I prefer to use option 1 because it's also better to choose a clean code. But I want to solve this issue

Comment: Special thanks @RaymondNijland , you let me figured out the solution.
Thanks all in advance.

Comment: *"no need for an exaggerated method name"*  Using self-explanatory code without abstraction and without needing to read documentation and or function comments is great but like i said before its a matter of tast and opinion..

Answer (score 0):

My database is InnoDB but i figured out that the tables is MyISAM.
solved by adding this line of code to migration: 
$table->engine = "InnoDB";